# remove jsessionid in url

Tags: jsf, jetty, session-cookies, jsessionid

I am facing a problem in jsf web application deployed in jetty web-server. When access application in browser, jsessionID is appended in the url. I want to remove it from there. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionURL` parameter to `none` in either the application web.xml or the context configuration.

See the [Jetty jsessionId documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/SessionIds).

Comment: hi McDowell thanks for reply , i tried this but, my problem is not solved. Although it hides jsessionid in url still i am not able to access next web page. I am using Pretty-config for hiding the actual page name in the url

Comment: Sounds like a different problem, though there isn't enough information to suggest a solution. Post a new question with enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have a web application in which some of the users are able to register from their machines while other are not able to despite using the same browser.Some of them get the jsession-id appended in url while others don't.

Comment: @nishant contractor - I would verify that the affected users have session cookies enabled in their browser. You'll see this in the [headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie) which you can get them to capture (e.g. by getting them to use FiddlerCap to capture the traffic and then analysing it in Fiddler)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by Setting Session Characteristics. Set the context parameter `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionIdPathParameterName` to `none` to disable url rewriting and prevent the jsession id appended to URL.

In web.xml,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionIdPathParameterName</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or if you are using annotation config instead of web.xml,

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
       servletContext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionIdPathParameterName", "none");
}
```

Refer: [Jetty's Session Management](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-management.html)