# how to prevent Jetty from inserting Session token in the url?

Tags: java, jetty

I am having some problems with a web app am working on written in Java EE with hibernate and spring.

the issue is that sometimes when the user has authenticated , the jetty app server will just inject the url with that user's session ID. Its my first time using Jetty and hibernate, where should i begin to stop this security flaw from happening ?

Comment: Why do you think that this has something to do with Hibernate? Hibernate does nothing with requests / responses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove jsessionid in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820120/remove-jsessionid-in-url)